# I am trying to deploy a docker file using minikube , deployment seems to be successful using yaml file but IP address is unreachable ,

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, dockerfile, minikube

aditya@Adityas-MacBook-Air ubuntu-image-go % `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
bat4-7d596d9688-9zfht   1/1     Running   1 (10m ago)   23h
```

aditya@Adityas-MacBook-Air ubuntu-image-go % `kubectl get service bat4`

```
NAME   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
bat4   LoadBalancer   10.100.160.169   127.0.0.1     8080:31806/TCP   23h
```

aditya@Adityas-MacBook-Air ubuntu-image-go % `kubectl get deployment bat4`

```
NAME   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
bat4   1/1     1            1           23h
```

these are the updates , I have also used command -- (`minikube tunnel`) to get external ip for my deployment

after running `minikube service bat4` , terminal opens an IP address but site is unreachable

my container is in a public repository on docker hub so that it can be accessed ,

I used the following commands

```
minikube start

eval $(minikube docker-env)

docker build -t aps1926/my-golang-app:latest .

kubectl get deployments
kubectl get pods
kubectl get services

minikube service bat4
```

I have tried commands like (port-forward) also but result is still the same ,

my yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bat4
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-golang-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-golang-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: interesting-bartik
        image: aps1926/my-golang-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: "512Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "0.5"
            memory: "256Mi"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bat4
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-golang-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

please help with the solutions